# Миграция c Vuex standart mode → Vuex module [Длинно-пост]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, модули, nuxt.js

Ребят, будет длинно-пост, ибо пригорело что-то.. 
Буду рад если вы не пройдете мимо или скажете что я не прав и херню наворотил :)

Писал себе спокойно я проект на Nuxt, писал-писал, долго писал, когда начал писать еще только Nuxt 2.1 был, а сейчас уже последняя версия аж на 2.6.Х. Почитал про обновления, как у них теперь все хорошо стало, много багов пофиксили, все работать намного быстрее мол стало, smart prefetching добавили и т.д и т.п

И черт меня дернул взять да попробовать обновить весь проект, как оказалось, если использовать менеджер пакетов npm, а не yarn, при обновлении могут возникнуть очень много проблем и проект нужно предварительно почистить. Долго мучался, искал что да как, но в итоге смог обновится с горем пополам.. 
Захожу в проект и меня встречает мааааленький такой варнинг: "classic mode for store/ is deprecated in nuxt 3.0". Ну думаю, отлично, и чем это нам сейчас придется пользоваться в Vuex ? Ползу в документацию и вижу что происходит переход в пользу модульного Vuex. 
И вот тут я начал действительно подгорать, потому что не понятно зачем, почему, и как..

Если ранее моя структура vuex была прекрасно оформлена что-то вроде:

```
index.js
user.js
website.js
```

А каждый из них был по примеру

```
*before*
export default { 
  state: { ... }, 
  mutations: { ... }, 
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}
```

И все было прекрасно и все было понятно, а сейчас я должен использовать почему-то синтаксис модулей который заставляет меня использовать постоянный export

```
*after*
export const state = () => ({ ... })
export const mutations = { ... }
export const actions = { ... }
export const getters = { ... }
```

Но и это как оказалось еще маленькая часть беды. Внутри Vue компонентов, я теперь должен обращаться именно к отдельному модулю из хранилища Vuex (?) Что как мне кажется полностью ломает саму концепцию Vuex (Все данные хранятся в одном месте).
И при вызове

```
before    this.$store.commit('{имя_метода}')
```

я еще и должен дописать перед именем метода имя файла модуля

```
after    this.$store.commit('user/{имя_метода}').
```

И вишенкой на торте стало невозможность обратится к из одного модуля, к другому внутри самого Vuex.

Если ранее внутри я обращался просто к имени метода к примеру

```
before    commit('setLoading', true)
```

То теперь так сделать не получится если такой мутации не содержится в данном модуле. Однако если он содержится в корневом модуле Vuex к нему можно будет обратится следующим образом

```
after    commit('setLoading', true, {root: true})
```

Как обратится из не корневого модуля в другой не корневой, для меня до сих пор остается загадкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот сейчас достаточно абстрактный вопрос.. А для чего собственно делать то это было, к чему такое усложнение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, [можно **отключить `namespaced`**](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/5189), добавив соответствующий export в файл модуля:

```
export const namespaced = false;
```

---

Во-вторых, **обратиться из одного модуля в другой** [можно добавив имя второго модуля в качестве префикса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606829/5812238):

```
commit('ИМЯ_ДРУГОГО_МОДУЛЯ/ИМЯ_ДЕЙСТВИЯ', null, { root: true })
```

---

В-третьих, в namespaced модуле [можно сделать действие глобальным](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/modules.html#%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B3n%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0n%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83n%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD).

---

В-четвёртых, вы можете [проголосовать за оставление classic mode](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4935) или [дать обратную связь напрямую разработчикам nuxt](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4681).